# Gentoo start up kde error after installed kdm

Tags: linux, kde, gentoo

My plasma desktop environment worked very well before I installed `kdm` display manager.But after I installed the `kdm` and reboot my laptop, Gentoo booted into a black screen with a white checkbox, which was saying

```shell
  Could not start kdeinit5, Check your installation.
```

Then I clicked the `okay` button. It dropped down into the tty with some error messages.

```shell
  xauth: file /root/.serverauth.8002 does not exist

  X.Org X Server 1.18.4
  Release Date: 2016-7-19
  X Protocol Version 11: Revision 0
  Build Operatin System: Linux 4.4.39-gentoo #1 SMP Fri Jan 13 20:24:54 CST 2017 x86_64
  Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/kernel-genkernel-x86_64-4.4.39-gentoo root=/dev/sda2 rootfstype=ext4 
  Build Date: 13 January 2017 11:03:46PM

  Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
  Before reporting problems., check http://wiki.x.org
  to make sure that you have the latest version.

  (==) Log File: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Jan 20 21:12:01 2017 
  (==) Using config directory "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
  (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
  The application failed to start because it could not find not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcd" in ""

  Available platform plugins are: wayland-org.kde.kwin.qpa, minimal, offscreen, wayland, xcb.
  Reinstalling the application may finx this problem.
  startkde: Starting up...
  /usr/bin/kdeinit5: relocation error: /usr/lib64/libQt5Gui.so.5: symbol _Z10qAllocMoreii, version Qt_5 not defined in file libQt5Core.so.5 with link time reference.
  startkde: Could not start kdeinit5. Check your installation.
  xinit: connection to X server lost.
  waiting for X server to shut down (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

However, it works pretty well before I installed `kdm`. I don't know why it crashed after I had installed `kdm`.

I also had found some advice from the Internet and tried. But those all didn't work. Can anyone give some solutions or some clues? My environment is:

- plasma version is: plasma-5.26.0
- kdm version is: kde-plasma/kdm-4.11.22
- kernel version is 4.4.39

Comment: Looks like some kind of Qt version mismatch. Did kdm install another version of Qt?

Comment: @StefanR I don't know exactly. how to check it out?

Comment: @StefanR Maybe it is, because I have noticed that there two versions of qt in  my `/usr/lib64` directory, one is `qt4` , another is `qt5` ,  but can  you  tell me how to resolve this problem and make my kde work again? thanks a lot.

Comment: It's really long time since I have used gentoo.. But the Qt version 5 is the one you want to be using here. So you should check that did you install correct version of KDM. How did you install it, what command did you use? I would remove that, because it is probably older than rest of the KDE you have installed.

Comment: But the newest version of kdm in my portage is 4.11.22, how can I get the newer one? And I have tried to uninstall the `kdm` and use the `sddm ` and `xdm`, this error still be there.

Comment: Hmm... maybe try to reinstall qt5 "emerge -av @qt5-essentials @qt5-addons" ?

Comment: @StefanR I tried to run `emerge -av @qt5-essentials @qt5-addons` command, but I got a new problem. the error message showed that there are some package is blocking the process. `[blocks b      ] <dev-qt/qtquickcontrols-5.7:5 ("<dev-qt/qtquickcontrols-5.7:5" is blocking dev-qt/qtdeclarative-5.7.1)`, can you tell me how to solve this conflict? thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52934/discussion-between-resrelentelss-and-stefanr).

Comment: @StefanR after having tried the solution which you provided, I solved this nerve-cut problem. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, thanks to @StefanR for saving my lots of time!
  Just as methioned by @StefanR above, this problem is caused by Qt version mismatched. After I removed the `kdm` by `emerge -C kdm` and updated some stuff referred `qt` by `emerge -av @qt5-essentials @qt5-addons`, my kde desktop environment works again as a charm.

**Must be mentioned**

if you portage claimed that  `There are no sets to satisfy 'qt5-essentials'` or `There are no sets to satisfy '@qt5-addons'`, you maybe lack some layers in your system, solved by using following command:

```shell
  emerge layman
  layman -S
  layman -a qt
  layman -a gentoo 
  emerge --ask @qt5-essentials @qt5-addons
```